# How do I call an updateString methos from my HUDLayer in my PlayLayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I'm making an iPhone game. I've tried to implement a nice architecture but I think it's went against me. I have 2 layers for my PlayScene; HUDLayer and PlayLayer. These 2 are classes which are instantiated as layers in the SceneManager class and both added to PlayScene.

The question is though, how do I gain access to my HUD class from my PlayLayer class? I need to access it from PlayLayer as that's where all the movement/event code is.

These are the methods in the SceneManager class which create the scene.

```
+(void) goPlay
{
    CCLayer *hudLayer = [HUD node];
    CCLayer *playLayer = [PlayLayer node];
    hudTag = playLayer.tag;

    [SceneManager goWithHud: playLayer: hudLayer: hudTag];
} 


+ (CCScene *) goWithHud:(CCLayer *) playLayer:(CCLayer *) hudLayer:(int)hudTag {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CCScene *newScene = [CCScene node];
    [newScene addChild: playLayer];
    [newScene addChild: hudLayer z:0 tag:hudTag];

    if([director runningScene])
           [director replaceScene:newScene];
    else 
       [director runWithScene:newScene];
    return newScene;
}
```

So I've got the HUD class which acts as the HUDLayer and the PlayLayer class which as all the movement/event code in.

How do I set the string on one of the labels in the HUD, and where should I do it from? I've tried many approaches, but I think it's my lack of understand of Obj-C more than anything.

If you need any more code, tell me; I just don't wanna spam a load of it in there if it's not needed.

Thanks in advance guys :).

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be like this (This will provide lose coupling and proper responsibility division.)

As you have `SceneManager` which has both the layers. You can use `delegation` or `notification` pattern to inform `SceneManager` that their is some motion or event in `PlayLayer` (delegate methods (or userInfo in case of notification) will provide necessary information that `SceneManager`  will use to configure `HUDLayer`).

**Update:**

In this case rather than using `SceneManager` class for handling delegate methods(as all methods are *`static`*) you will need to use the class from where you operate on `SceneManager`.(I will call it `'X'`). So X will be handling the delegation or notification. Also to provide observer you will need to pass `X` into the `goPlay` method.

So your `goPlay` method declaration will become:

```
+(CCScene *) goPlayWithEventObserver:(id)observer;
```

Also, from `goPlay` method you will need to return the scene object to `X`, which will  help `X` to access its child(`HUDLayer`) by calling `getChildByTag` method. You can get instance of `PlayLayer` from its delegate or it can provide it in `userInfo`.

Thanks,

Comment: This makes sense to me. But I'm unsure of the syntax to create such objects, how do I refer to my HUDLayer? When instantiating it it would be a HUD object, but because I must instantiate it as a CCLayer it gives me a ''CCLayer' may not respond to updateString' warning in SceneManager.

Comment: It seems I can't call the method even from SceneManager because it won't let me access HUD's methods as it becomes a CCLayer upon initialization of the class?

Comment: Thanks Ravin, I'm about to pull my hair out so I'm going to stop now and give it a go tomorrow. I'll get back to you! I can't upvote your post because of my lacking reputation. Got to say though, it's so good having such a good community like this on the internet, which is a rare find sometimes... :)